# A little help with timer app (Please)

Tags: c#, winforms

I do primarily web stuff, but I've been playingnaround with a simple windws form app. I want create a timer, a stopwatch of sort with a start and stop buttons. I have no idea wher to begin so I googled for examples. Found one, and kuddos to the original coder for sharing it, but I cant get it to work. It was origibnally written as console app so my sortcoming is how to tie it to a windows form.

I started by creatig a windows form app, added a label and two buttons to the form. Next I renamed the program.cs to StopWatch.cs and pasted this code. Created a label and assigned the method that returne the clock to the label's text property. But it's notworkig - so would like your comment as to what I'm doing wrong. See the code below. Thanks - Risho.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StopWatch
{
    public class StopWatch
    {
        private DateTime startTime;
        private DateTime stopTime;
        private bool running = false;


        public void Start()
        {
            this.startTime = DateTime.Now;
            this.running = true;
        }


        public void Stop()
        {
            this.stopTime = DateTime.Now;
            this.running = false;
        }


        // elaspsed time in milliseconds
        public double GetElapsedTime()
        {
            TimeSpan interval;

            if (running)
                interval = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            else
                interval = stopTime - startTime;

            return interval.TotalMilliseconds;
        }


        // elaspsed time in seconds
        public double GetElapsedTimeSecs()
        {
            TimeSpan interval;

            if (running)
                interval = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            else
                interval = stopTime - startTime;

            return interval.TotalSeconds;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            StopWatch s = new StopWatch();
            s.Start();

            s.Stop();

            Label lblTimer = new Label();

            lblTimer.Text = s.GetElapsedTime().ToString();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include what errors you are getting.

Comment: There is a ready-to-use StopWatch-Class in .NET.

Comment: Yup, and I use it in my example :)

Comment: @Darren, I'm not getting any errors, just blank form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you are doing, is basically rewriting the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class right?

So, what if your rename the stopwatch class to `Program` and remove all the code in the `Main` method except for these lines:

```
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
 Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 Application.Run(new Form1());
```

And then, in your `Form1` class,

```
 using System.Diagnostics;

 public partial class Form1 : Form {

     Stopwatch s;

 ...

     private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (s == null)
              s = new Stopwatch();

         s.Restart();
     }

     private void btnEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if (s == null)
              return;

           s.Stop();

          lblElapsed.Text = s.Elapsed;
     }
 ...      

 }
```

This requires that you have three things in the designer:

- Two buttons, called btnStart, and btnEnd respectively
- A label called lblElapsed.

btnStart and btnEnd must be have their `Click` methods hooked up, and insert the code respectively.

Please note that this doesn't update the text in the label constantly, it only updates every time you click the stop button.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. @Richard: In my Form.cs file the intellisense won't give the same properties of the stopwatch (Elapsed, Restart, etc). It is only available in the program.cs file.

Comment: Did you add the using statement? Also, make sure the files have the same namespace.

Comment: Got System.Diagnostics, and same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Your stopwatch class is fine. However your main method is not.

You need to place your label on Form1 and set the label text on an event like click of a button.

You can follow this simple steps -

1. Goto the design view of the form in
   Visual Studio
2. Open the toolbox and drag-drop a
   label and a button control on the
   form
3. In the properties window give
   appropriate names to the controls by
   editing the Name property
4. double click the button in design
   view and you will be navigated to
   its click event in the code view.
5. set the label text in the click
   event of the button.

I googled and found these resources as good starting point to learn winForms

http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=winforms+tutorials&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=98a02fd89f148227

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are in the wrong file, the program.cs file which you renamed creates the form and nothing else. You want to be doing your stopwatch code in the form itself. The form1.cs file (I think it's called that).